# Can we merge two dgml diagrams into a single one?

Tags: wcf, merge, dependencies, diagram, dgml

We host 3 WCF services through IIS. They all inter communicate with each other. Through Architecture explorer, I can get their individual dependency diagrams including the function level details. What im looking at is to have one merged diagram probably, to get the complete picture? My idea was to merge the diagrams based on the contracts definition probably... 
Is there a tool available which does this? or Any other ideas are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried copy/paste? If the identifiers on the nodes match then the paste operation does behave like a merge.

To help make the identifiers match, you may want to place the assemblies you are visualizing all in the same folder so the full path of each assembly is the same in all 3 diagrams, then the merge will work better.

Alternately, you can drag all the assemblies to the same graph, or you can use **Select Files...** in **Architecture Explorer** to select all of your assemblies, then choose the **Open** action in the next column instead of **Contains**, and then you can produce a single dependency graph containing all the code you care about.

Comment: May be i should be a bit more clearer with the requirements: Service1.Operation1 talks to Service2.Operation1 and Service2.Operation1 talks to Service3.Operation1 and Service3.Operation2. The final output that i would like to have is, a single diagram showing the real dependency between all services.
The way you have asked me to do, would only give me three individual blocks of Services.
What im looking at is, an integrated diagram, where i can see all the real dependencies between all the services.

Comment: OK, try this instead:

In Architecture Explorer, select everything you want to visualize, and then on the Architecture Explorer toolbar, click Create new graph document from all the selected nodes. 

After the graph appears, right-click the graph, point to Group, and then click Show All as Groups. 

On the graph toolbar, click the drop-down arrow for Change how links are rendered on the graph, and then select Show All Cross-Group Links.

You should then see the operations nested inside the services, and dependencies between the operations.